# App is removed because of Unauthorized Use of Copyrighted Content

Tags: google-play

I published an app on play store, it was on play store for a few weeks, but recently my application is removed from play store.
After re_checking my app, i found that my app has an activy that shows film trailer image. if user click on an image my app will play film trailer video.
My question is : Is this the main reason of app removing on play store?

Comment: Your app publish again ?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there are a lot of reasons an app can be removed from Google Play. They could be:

- Because in your description of your app, you use the names of some famous apps. This will violate the metadata policy of Google.
- Because you use some copyrighted content without evidence of permission or something like that.
- Because the name of your app contains some words of other popular apps.

Usually, they won't remove your app unless you update a newer version. But sometimes they check it manually for some random apps, then your app will be removed.

But don't worry too much, you can re-publish your app again with the same number of installs and ratings.

Comment: But there is lots of application on google play same like this.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I don't have exactly the way they check. Usually they do it automatically, sometimes they do it manually. So you just need to follow their instructions to get your apps up on the store for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the Title, Short Description, and Long Descriptions.